Как сделать слайдер с кнопками в Android Jetpack Compose
Всем привет! Как можно реализовать горизонтальный слайдер с кнопками, который должен перекидывать пользователя на необходимые экраны в Jetpack Compose? 

Если нельзя, то чем можно было бы заменить?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Это элементарно делается даже без HorisontalPager на голом Compose с помощью кнопки, одного Box со switch и прогрессбара либо готового, либо опять же Box/Spacer с рисованием заливки. Но без вашего кода тут либо подскажут направление (вот как я), либо просто не ответят.
